# Services Browser in Services 3

Tags: 7, services

I just switch from drupal 6 services 2 to drupal 7 services 3. I'm having  little trouble figuring out how to configure services, I'm used to being able to test different services using the services browser, but it seems like there is no services browser in services 3, does anyone have a good method for do these test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://drupal.org/node/790416.  There is a Firefox addon called [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) which you can use or there is one for Chrome called [REST Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/faceofpmfclkengnkgkgjkcibdbhemoc).

Answer (score 0):

Theres also [Fetcher](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fetcher/id440113616?mt=12%20), on the app store if you are on a Mac